# Interior Points Question of S in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ be equipped with the norm $\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert = \lvert x_1\rvert + \lvert x_2\rvert$ and let $S = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1 + x_2 > 0\}.$ How would I find the interior points of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I didn't really get anywhere meaningful, so I decided to do the problem in $\mathbb{R}$ as opposed to $\mathbb{R}^2$ .

My working out:

Let $y \in S =  \mathbb{R}^+$. Then, $B(y,\epsilon) = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R} : \lVert y-x\rVert < \epsilon\} = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R} : \lvert y-x\rvert < \epsilon\} = \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}: y-\epsilon<x<y+\epsilon\}.$ For $y$ to be an interior point of S, we want $B(y,\epsilon)$ to lie inside $S$. For this to happen, we want $y-\epsilon>0$ and so $y>\epsilon$. Thus $B(y,\epsilon)\subseteq S.$ Since $y$ was arbitrary that means that every element of S is an interior point. <s>Does that mean there are no boundary points?</s>

Edit: Does that mean that $S$ doesn't contain any of its boundary points?

As for doing the problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$, I just got stuck at the inequality $\lvert y_1-x_1\rvert+\lvert y_2-x_2\rvert < \epsilon$ and wasn't sure how to choose an $\epsilon$ such that $x_1+x_2 > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture it is 'clear' that $S$ is already open.

Assume that $y_1 + y_2 = \epsilon > 0$

Now take $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ ball around $(y_1, y_2)$. This works since,

$|x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2| < \epsilon/2$ gives

$|y_1 + y_2 - (x_1 + x_2)| < \epsilon/2$

So, $y_1+ y_2 - (x_1 + x_2) < \epsilon/2$

$\implies x_1 + x_2 > \epsilon/2$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for $\mathbb{R}$, every element belonging to $S$ is interior. Yes, $S$ doesn't contain its boundary points.

For $\mathbb{R}^2$ case, for any **x**$(x_1, x_2)$ let $\epsilon = x_1 + x_2$, then consider a ball **B**(**x**, $\epsilon$), I'll let you verify **B**(**x**, $\epsilon$) $\subset S $.

Now, how to find the suitable value of $\epsilon$? Just from the observation we know that line $x+y=0$ is the boundary of $S$. Hence, for any **x**$(x_1, x_2)$ you just have to find the L1 distance of **x** from the line $x+y=0$ (let's say it comes out to be '$d$'), you can simply set $\epsilon$ = $d$ (or $d/2$, as @subham has done)